# Remove members of a list in another list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a program that checks if a word or sentence given by user input is a palindrome or not. This is the program so far:

```
def reverse(text):
    a = text[::-1]
    if a == text:
        print "Yes, it's a palindrome."
    else:
        print "No, it's not a palindrome."

string = str(raw_input("Enter word here:")).lower()

reverse(string)
```

However, this code doesn't work for sentences. So I tried to do it like this:

```
import string

def reverse(text):
    a = text[::-1]
    if a == text:
        print "Yes, it's a palindrome."
    else:
        print "No, it's not a palindrome."

notstring = str(raw_input("Enter word here:")).lower()

liststring = list(notstring)

forbiddencharacters = string.punctuation + string.whitespace

listcharacters = list(forbiddencharacters)

newlist = liststring - listcharacters

finalstring = "".join(newlist)

reverse(finalstring)
```

My goal is to put the punctuation and whitespace into a list and then subtracting those characters to the input of the user so that the program can tell if it's a palindrome even if the string has punctuation and/or whitespace. However, I don't know how I can subtract the elements in a list to the elements in another list. The way I did it, by creating another list that equals the user input minus the characters doesn't work (I tried it in my Xubuntu terminal emulator). Apart from that, when I run the program this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reverse.py", line 12, in <module>
    forbiddencharacters = string.punctuation + string.whitespace
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'punctuation'
```

Ok so I have changed the variable name and I don't get that mistake above. Now I still don't know how to subtract the elements of the lists.

Since I'm a beginner programmer this might seem stupid to you. If that's the case, I'm sorry in advance. If anyone can solve one or both of the two problems I have, I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks in advance for your help. Sorry for bad english and long post :)

Comment: don't use string as a variable name and then try to use the  string module

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that

Comment: don't call `str()` on the returned value from `raw_input()` it is already has `str` type.

Comment: related: [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/265960/4279).

Comment: Ok J.F Sebastian, I will no longer use str(). However I didn't understand most of what is in the related post, but don't bother explaining it to me, I'll look things up

Comment: you should rename `reverse()` to `print_is_palindrome()`

Comment: Why should I change the name of the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add some filtering along the way since palindromes have various syntax tricks (spaces, commas, etc.).

```
palindrome = "Rail at a liar"

def is_palindrome(text):
    text = text.lower()                               #Avoid case issues
    text = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch.isalnum()) #Strips down everything but alphanumeric characters
    return text == text[::-1]

if is_palindrome(palindrome):
    print "Yes, it's a palindrome."
else:
    print "No, it's not a palindrome."
```

Comment: Yours is better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by splitting the phrase and storing it in a list. I am going to use your function (but there are more better pythonic ways to do that).

```
def reverse(textList1):
    textList2 = textList1[::-1]  #or we can use reversed(textList1)
    if textList2 == text:
        print "Yes, it's a palindrome."
    else:
        print "No, it's not a palindrome."

test1= "I am am I"

You should split the phrase and store it in a list:
test1List= test1.split(' ')

reverse(test1List)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but you have used the identifier `string` for two different purposes.

Since you assigned to this variable name with the line:

```
string = str(raw_input("Enter word here:")).lower()
```

You can now no longer access the attributes `string.punctuation` and `string.whitespace` from the `import string`, because the name `string` is no longer bound to the module but to the user input instead.

Comment: Ok I changed the name of the variable and now I don't get that mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat different approach to testing if a string is a palindrome

```
def palindrome(s):
    s = s.lower()
    ln=len(s)
    for n in xrange(ln/2):
        if s[n] != s[(ln-n)-1]:
            return False
    return True

print palindrome('Able was I ere I saw Elba')
```

FYI -- you'll need to tweak this to strip punctuation and white space if you like (left an an exercise to OP)

Comment: Thanks for the exercise I'll definitely try it your way because I need to learn a lot

Answer (score 0):

Checking for palindrome is simple,

This works for both words and sentences.

```
import string

def ispalindrome(input_str):
    input_str = list(input_str)
    forbidden = list(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)

    for forbidden_char in forbidden:              # Remove all forbidden characters
        while forbidden_char in input_str:
            input_str.remove(forbidden_char)
    return input_str == list(reversed(input_str)) # Checks if it is a palindrome


input_str = raw_input().lower()    # Avoid case issues
print ispalindrome(input_str)      # Get input
```